Understanding diamond problem in inheritance
I'm trying to understand the diamond problem through the following code:
#implement Hybrid Inheritance

class University:
    def __init__(self,univ_name):
        self.univ_name=univ_name
    def show_details(self):
        print(f"University Name : {self.univ_name}")

class Course(University):
    def __init__(self, univ_name,course_name):
        super().__init__(univ_name)
        self.course_name=course_name
    
    def show_details(self):
        super().show_details()
        print(f"Course_name : {self.course_name}")

class Branch(University):
    def __init__(self, univ_name, branch_name):
        super().__init__(univ_name)
        self.branch_name=branch_name

    def show_details(self):
        super().show_details()
        print(f"Branch_name : {self.branch_name}")

class Student(Course,Branch):
    def __init__(self, univ_name, course_name,branch_name):
        Course.__init__(self,univ_name, course_name)
        Branch.__init__(self,univ_name,branch_name)
    def show_details(self):
        Course.show_details(self)
        Branch.show_details(self)

std_1=Student("UTL","Masters","CSE")
std_1.show_details()

When I run the code, I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Assignements\Exercise_4.py", line 35, in <module>
    std_1=Student("UTL","Masters","CSE")
  File "\Assignements\Exercise_4.py", line 29, in __init__
    Course.__init__(self,univ_name, course_name)
  File "\Assignements\Exercise_4.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__(univ_name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'branch_name'

Is the above error due to the diamond problem, and how can it be resolved?

The hierarchy is terrible to begin with. A Course isn't a University. A Student is neither a Course nor a Branch. These should all be completely separate classes. — A hierarchy that does make sense would be Person → Teacher, Student. Both teachers and students are persons and probably share most of their attributes. That can not be said about what you have. — Look into composition instead of inheritance.

@deceze Although the particular hierarchy may be questionable, the actual question is still reasonable, don't you think? Assuming the class hierarchy would represent a more meaningful hierarchy/dependency of concepts, the observed behavior would still be the same, and might likewise come as a surprise.

@simon Sure, the details of this are answerable, which is why I didn't vote to close or anything like that; but the entire issue could be avoided entirely with a more sensible class hierarchy.

@deceze Agreed. I guess a really good answer would therefore address both aspects: the actual question and the particular, questionable design choice for the underlying problem.

Hi @deceze,@simon thanks for your suggestions can you please help me to understand why that error occurred, im beginner to the topic

In a nutshell: because super() refers to the next class in the MRO, which is not necessarily the direct parent class. When inheriting from two classes, the MRO may not be what you expect. Looking at just Course or Branch by themselves, super().__init__ will be what you immediately expect. But in the multi-inheritance scenario in Student, it's not.

You can get the __mro__ attribute (meaning method resolution order)  to see the class hierarchy:
print(Student.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.Student'>, <class '__main__.Course'>, <class '__main__.Branch'>, <class '__main__.University'>, <class 'object'>)

So in the case of a student, the Course class is calling  super().__init__ on the Branch class. This could be fixed by doing like what you did for the Student class and doing:
University.__init__(self, univ_name)

In the Branch and Course classes.
A better way to solve it would be to use composition:
A University has courses and branches. Courses have students. Branches have students:
class University:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.courses: list[Course] = []
        self.branches: list[Branch] = []

    def add_course(self, course):
        self.courses.append(course)

    def add_branch(self, branch):
        self.branches.append(branch)

    def show_details(self):
        print(f"University Name: {self.name}")
        print("Courses Offered:")
        for course in self.courses:
            course.show_details()
        print("Branches Available:")
        for branch in self.branches:
            branch.show_details()


class Course:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.students = []

    def show_details(self):
        print(f"Course Name: {self.name}")
        print("Students: ")
        for student in self.students:
            student.show_details()

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)


class Branch:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.students: list[Student] = []

    def show_details(self):
        print(f"Branch Name: {self.name}")
        print("Students: ")
        for student in self.students:
            student.show_details()

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)


class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def show_details(self):
        print(f"Student Name: {self.name}")


def main():
    university = University("UTL")

    course_masters = Course("Masters")
    branch_cse = Branch("CSE")

    university.add_course(course_masters)
    university.add_branch(branch_cse)

    student = Student("John Doe")
    course_masters.add_student(student)
    branch_cse.add_student(student)
    university.show_details()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
University Name: UTL
Courses Offered:
Course Name: Masters
Students: 
Student Name: John Doe
Branches Available:
Branch Name: CSE
Students: 
Student Name: John Doe

You could restructure this for your usecase.

Hi @Tom McLean thanks for your answer but can u explain what went actually wrong in my version of code due to which i got the error I'm actually a beginner to this topic i want the exact reason for error

Read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/. You aren't consistently using super in every class of your hierarchy. In some sense the MRO solves the diamond problem by defining a specific ordering of classes with which to resolve inherited methods, so Student doesn't inherit show_details from Branch and Course, only from Course, because Course precedes Branch in the MRO of an instance of Student.
